# How to remove ubuntu 11.10 from dual boot

Tags: 12.04, 11.10

I upgraded from **11.10** to **12.04LTS** using **iso** file i downloaded . But i realized that **12.04LTS** is installed in parellel with 11.10. How do i remove 11.10

Answer (score 0):

I would boot in to 12.04.  Install Gparted from the software centre. Then use Gparted to delete the partition 11.10 is on and resize your 12.04 partition to reclaim the space.

This will require a little bit of knowledge of your disc partitions.  Be careful not to remove the wrong thing.